# How to print out elements of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just got started with python, now I need to print out the names of elements/objects/instances of a class, this is my code:

```
class Delicious : 
    sweet = 0
    sour = 0

apple = Delicious()
kiwi = Delicious()
litchi = Delicious()

bracket = [apple, kiwi, lichi]

print(bracket)
```

I ran it in the terminal, it prints out:
[<**main**.Delicious object at 0x1019d9940>, <**main**.Delicious object at 0x1019d9978>, <**main**.Delicious object at 0x1019d99b0>]
how do I make it print `apple` `kiwi` `litchi`?

The other answers are too hard for me, can somebody answer it simply?

Comment: You need an indent of four spaces before sweet and sour. It wont work without it.

Comment: `apple = Delicious()` in order to create an *instance* of `Delicious` and `print(apple.sweet, apple.sour)` in order to print out its elements.

Comment: @Jim no I just need to print 'apple'

Comment: @Jim the name not its property value

Comment: What it should print if `apple = peach = Delicious()`? `apple` and `peach` is the same thing and should print same value, but you somehow assumes that once it should print apple, and another time peach. What it should print if `my_list = [apple]; print my_list[0]`?

Comment: You shouldn't try to access the name of variables. If you want to output `apple` or `kiwi` you should probably store your `Delecious` instances in a dict, i.e. `my_dict= {'apple': Delicious(), 'kiwi': Delicious()}` and then just `print(my_dict.keys())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get this to work is by grabbing the instances name from `globals()` and returning it from `__str__`:

```
class Delicious : 
    sweet = 0
    sour = 0

    def __str__(self):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if v == self:
                return k

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

Now printing will return the name as you defined it:

```
apple = Delicious()

print(apple)
apple
```

Printing a `list` that contains your objects will call their `__repr__`, so you can either also define `__repr__` to return `__str__`s result, or call `print(*bracket)` to unpack the list in the print call which uses their `__str__` function:

```
print(bracket)
[apple, kiwi, lichi]  

print(*bracket)
apple, kiwi, lichi
```

But this make 0 practical sense, in Python names are just labels assigned to objects, by using `print` and printing the name you get no information about the underlying object.